# ASP.NET CheckBoxField binding to oracle which has no boolean. Known work around?

Tags: .net, asp.net, oracle

I have a gridview controller with a set of BoundField columns to my data source. I also have a CheckBoxField that I want checked depending on if that row in the table I get from the database is marked accordingly. The problem is, Oracle does not have a boolean type and ASP.NET is expecting a boolean to mark the check box. Is there some sort of work around for this?

Here is my gridview with the check box column.

```
<asp:GridView ID="DeviceGridView" runat="server" CssClass="SmallGridView"  
       DataSourceID="DeviceDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       EmptyDataText="No devices found." CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
       GridLines="None"  OnRowCreated="GridView_RowCreated" 
       OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound"  >
    <FooterStyle CssClass="gridViewFooter" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="gridViewRow" />
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="gridViewEditRow" />
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gridViewSelectedRow" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeader" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridViewAltRow" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DeviceID" DataField="device_id" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Device Type" DataField="device_type" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="description" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Enable Logging" DataField="enable_logging" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="normal_toggle" Text="Normal User Logging" />
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<asp:CheckBoxField>`, try using a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" 
                      Checked='<%# Eval("normal_toggle") == 1 %>' 
                      AutoPostBack="true" 
                      OnCheckedChanged="YourCheckedChangedEvent"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

That will make your checkbox checked if `normal_toggle` value equals 1 and unchecked otherwise. Adjust to your data accordingly.

**Update**

Added an event to the `<asp:Checkbox>` inside the template field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It isn't exactly how I wanted it as I want to do a post back whenever something is checked. You did make me stumble upon the path I need to take, so I appreciate that.

Comment: I see you have ID="cb". What happens when I have multiple rows with this checkbox. How is the ID determined then?

Comment: Good question. Each line of the grid will have a checkbox with ID equal "cb". You can navigate the rows of the grid and use `FindControl`. But you don't need that, it's the clicked checkbox who triggers the event.

Comment: Ok, another question. How do I know which checkbox was checked when I enter that event?

Comment: How about posting a new question on the issue? :) I'd be happy to answer that!

Comment: Posted it. You should be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

`<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" 
        Checked='<%# Eval("normal_toggle").ToString() == "Y" ? true : false  %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>`

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to this issue
First I created my own CheckBox component.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

namespace Production_Manager.Util.Objects
{
    public class CheckBoxYN : System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox
    {
        public string YesNo
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Checked)
                    return "Y";
                else
                    return "N";
            }
            set
            {
                bool changed = false;
                if (value == "Y")
                {
                    if (!this.Checked)
                        changed = true;

                    this.Checked = true;

                    if (changed)
                        OnPropertyChanged("YesNo");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.Checked)
                        changed = true;

                    this.Checked = false;

                    if (changed)
                        OnPropertyChanged("YesNo");

                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

        }

        protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("YesNo");
            base.OnCheckedChanged(e);
        }    
}
}
```

Once you compile your project, the CheckBoxYN will appear in the toolbox.
In the Item and Edit Template place your object
YOURBOOLFIELD:
            ' />

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was cut off. add this the Edit/Item templates <cc1:CheckBoxYN ID="CheckBoxYN1" runat="server" YESNO='<%# Bind("YOURBOOLFIELD") %>' />

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old but I just spent a couple of hours trying to get this sorted for MYSQL and may work for ORACLE.

in your UPDATE or INSERT statement you can use this

column_name = IF(?='True',1,0)

VALUES (IF(?='True',1,0), ...)

no need to change a bound checkboxfield to an item template or anything.

I'm not sure if it matters but I changed my parameter type to Boolean and as I now have it working I don't want to change it.